# Is it legal to patent an idea and then not use it?

Tags: united-states, patents

In the HBO show Silicon Valley, [a patent describing a technique that could replace paid services with free ones](https://www.reddit.com/r/SiliconValleyHBO/comments/87eyk8/the_decentralized_internet_patent/) is an important plot point. The patent was never used and seems to have never had an intent to be used.

In the United States, is it possible for a corporation to receive a patent for an idea, so that they can *prevent* it from going to market and hurting their business?

I'm aware that [recent changes have targeted non-practicing entities](https://www.inc.com/nick-skillicorn/how-the-current-patent-system-actually-hurts-inventors.html), but it's unclear to me where the lines are.

Are there any notable real-world examples of this happening?

**Edits**

I've learned about [compulsory licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_license), but I'm curious about if those laws have been used to force a company to withholding a patent.

Comment: See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/31015/can-i-forbid-the-government-from-using-my-patented-invention/

Comment: It doesn't seem like that link really answers my question, since they're talking about a relationship with the government. But perhaps this could: https://law.stackexchange.com/a/31026/23552

Answer (score 2):

There is no "use it or lose it" concept in U.S. patent law. A patent does not even give its owner the right to use their invention, let alone mandate it. A patent, in any country, is fundamentally a right to prevent others from doing something. Some countries do have a "working" requirement, where the patent owner needs to agree to license their patent if they have not commercialized it themselves within a certain time limit. India is an example of a location that has compulsory licensing. 
There is a bias (in my view) against non-practicing entities that affects their ability to get an injunction against infringers.